# Failing to remove attributes of Tree View in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, treeview, qfilesystemmodel

I am a newbie in QT. I am working on a app where I need to display the FileSystem using a treeview.

Basically I have a widget in my .ui file on which I have put a Treeview. Then in my .cpp file I have written the following code:

```
model = new QFileSystemModel(this);
model->setRootPath(QDir::homePath());
ui->treeView->setModel(model);
```

In my .h file I have put the following:

```
QFileSystemModel *model;
```

When I run the app, it displays the file system inside the treeview but it also shows Name, Type, Size, DateModified above it. I want to get rid of these. 
Here is the sample Image:

[image]

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [QTreeView::hideColumn](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtreeview.html#hideColumn) does it.